# Check elements present in array using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, sorting, nested-loops

I have a situation where i want to check if elements in one array are present in another array. If elements are present, then push those in new array. In this case, i have array of strings.

For e.g.

```
var check = ["6003", "6005", "6010"]; //static values. I need to check these elements if they are present in InputValues

var InputValues = ["5005", 2005", "6010"]; //dynamic input values

var result = ["6010"]; //dyanimic final array based off elements in InputValues
```

Similary,

```
var InputValues = ["5005", 6005", "6010"];

var result = ["6005", "6010"];
```

Can someone please let me know how to achieve this dynamic result.

Comment: Probably a duplicate somewhere... but you can do `var set = new Set(check); var result = InputValues.filter(value => set.has(value));`

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37041756/1541563) seems very similar to my suggestion above, but also removes duplicates from both the input arrays before applying the filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var result = InputValues.filter((val) => check.includes(val));
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes#Browser_compatibility

edit: Used the wrong method! `.includes()` works if you do not care about IE (though it is in Edge), otherwise this is the "modern" on to use :-)

Comment: Yep - doh! Though gave an excuse to link to MDN for browser compatibility ;-)

Comment: You still called it `.contains()` in the following paragraph. And no, I would not call this the "modern" one to use. It's more semantic than `.indexOf(...) >= 0` but I would argue that using a `Set` and a `.has()` check like in my comment on the question would be an order of magnitude more efficient, because `.has()` is average O(1) time complexity while `.includes()` is O(n) time complexity.

Comment: Doh - I have no excuse beyond tiredness for that! Changing it into a `Set` and using that may be quicker depending on the length of the array, but unless you're caching the `Set` it's going to be significantly worse for the GC and overall performance - and given the simplicity of the question it's adding a whole lot of things that the OP will probably not understand! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) with [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
var result = InputValues.filter(elem => check.indexOf(elem) >= 0);
```

Basically what it does is, it will filter the elements of `InputValues` against `check` case-sensitive wise.